# how to generate javadoc in eclipse Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc

I try install java doc using following comment and got error.

sudo apt-get install sun-java6-doc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sun-java6-doc

Please help me to fix issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the openJDK instead of sun java. Sun java has been deprecated since Ubuntu 10.04, openJDK is now the default.

You can then install javadoc by installing the jdk:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

An interesting discussion about this topic can be found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1467722.html).

To generate the javadoc via Eclipse go to Project -> Generate Javadoc and then follow the steps.